# python pyinstaller pyqt add custom icons to the interface

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller

I have searched everywhere, I can't figure out how to add my own icons to the interface.

I don't need to know how to change the application icon or the title bar, what I need is for PyInstaller to add to the executable the images I use for buttons in the GUI once compiled.

The best I found was this, but it doesn't work:

`pyinstaller --clean --onefile --noconsole --icon="media/icon.png" -i="media/icon.png" --add-data="media/*;." main.py`

That my icons are shown in the buttons, but not the default PyQt icons, but the customized ones.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is ambiguous. What doesn't work? Are you sure that the files are not being included? Note that just because you don't see the icon, that doesn't mean that they are not in the bundle, but only that the program is not able to access them, possibly because you used the wrong path; for instance, you added the icons from the `media/` folder, but then you added them into the *root* folder, and if in your program you try to set an icon using `QIcon('media/myicon.png')`, it will not work, as you should've used `--add-data="media/*;media"` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! You were absolutely right, it does pack them, but not "in a sub path", when compiling, the paths should be direct and not relative as I was using them that are shown in the "main" without compiling.

Comment: you are way better off using the rcc tool and `.qrc` file, then you can just import the output python file and make them available that way.  https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/overviews/resources.html#the-qt-resource-system

Comment: I will then research that way, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `--one-file` flag, when the app executable is ran, pyinstaller unpacks all the files into a temporary directory, this temporary directory is then passed to `sys._MEIPASS`. So in order to access the icon files in your media folder the base directory should start from `sys._MEIPASS`.

```
import sys
from os import path
# If we're running the app as an executable or as a python script
if getattr(sys, "frozen", False):  
    # If it's an executable set the base directory to sys._MEIPASS
    base_directory = sys._MEIPASS
else:
    # Otherwise set it as the folder containing the main script
    base_directory = path.dirname(path.realpath("__file__"))

media_folder = path.join(base_directory, "media")
button_icon = path.join(media_folder, "button.png")
```

Additionally you don't have to specify the you `media/*` or use `;` as of the latest version of pyinstaller you simply say `--add-data=media:media`.